# AngularJS - Directive in combination with Jquery inside directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-plugins, angularjs-directive

How to achieve that I 'activate' `jQuery(element).scombobox()` inside a directive which is not ready a `<select>`.

To see more details please see the **[http://plnkr.co/edit](http://plnkr.co/edit/0wZZHxqCP3LXOaCHPdjF)**

And this is the html:

```
<div tu-combobox="" ng-model="comboboxvalue" options="combobox.options"></div>
```

I've got this directive:

```
.directive('tuCombobox', function($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
                feature: '=',
                options: '=',
                tudisabled: '='
            },
            template: '<select ng-disabled="tudisabled" ng-options="option.value as option.text for option in options"></select>',
            link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {


  // this doesn't work because the template isn't yet rendered
            //element.scombobox();


  // but using this i get a bunch of errors $rootScope:inprogress

          scope.$watch('ngModel', function(){
            element.scombobox();
           });


          }
        };
    })
```

Why is this so hard to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Since the template is retrieved asynchronously (even if locally available, e.g. in `$templateCache`) you need to execute yout code after Angular has completed its "stuff".
The safest here is to use `$timeout` to execute your code after all pending operations have been completed.

---

E.g.:

```
.directive('tuCombobox', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        ...
        link: function tuComboboxPostLink(scope, elem) {
            $timeout(function () {
                elem.scombobox();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

---

**[Updated plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7LNVAi0nnZqEDttFHFJN?p=preview)**

Comment: Hi, Thanks, this fixes the problems with the $rootScope: inprogress. But I'm using about 60 comboboxes in a grid, and now there is a visual delay when they get converted to a `scombobox()`

Answer (score 0):

Bellow I tried to adapt a jquery datetimepicker directive to your combobox, I didn't compile it, so you'll need to polish it.

```
.directive('tuCombobox', function($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            replace: true,
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
                feature: '=',
                options: '=',
                tudisabled: '='
            },
            compile: function(element, attrs) {
                var modelAccessor = $parse(attrs.ngModel);

                var html = '<select ng-disabled="tudisabled" ng-options="option.value       as option.text for option in options"></select>';

                var newElem = $(html);
                element.replaceWith(newElem)

        return function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {

           var processSelection = function () {
                var selection = element.combox("getvalue");
                scope.$apply(function (scope) {
                    // Change bound variable
                    modelAccessor.assign(scope, selection;
                });
            };
            //if option is selected on UI
            element.combobox({onSelect:processSelection});

            //If option is set from code
            scope.$watch(modelAccessor, function(val){
                element.combobox("setValue",val);
              })
          }
            }
        };
    });
```